# Get woocommerce REST API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have just built my woocommerce on my wordpress on ubuntu server. I have installed woocommerce REST API as a plugin and activated it. I would like to know how can I call my data? is it this way to call? ---> http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders

Comment: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#retrieve-an-order

Comment: thanks for the info! when I access the link above, I will get Not Found in the web. I would like to know what steps I missed out.